# how can i make this specific part of my website responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

So im trying to make this page responsive going really well except this part. There is 4 circles and i need it to be right next to the 4 question that are stacked on top of each other. I have tried everything including using all the things like px % vh em rem and also i have tried wrapping it in a div and other things still couldn't get it to work. If someone could help i would be very thankful.

```js
//Question bank
var questionBank = [{
    question: 'تصویر زیر چیست؟<br><img src="https://www.linkpicture.com/q/angur.jpg" typ="image" id="img1"><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:36.819%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(4).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:46.958%;"><audio controls  controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:57.097%;"><audio controls  controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(2).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:67.235%;"><audio controls  controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(3).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div>',
    option: ['ابر', 'انگور', 'اسب', 'اره'],
    answer: 'انگور'
  },
  {
    question: 'تصویر زیر چیست؟<br><img src="https://www.linkpicture.com/q/asb.jpg" typ="image" id="img2"><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:36.819%;"><audio controls  controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:46.958%;"><audio  controls  controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(4).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:57.097%;"><audio controls  controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(4).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:67.235%;"><audio controls  controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(3).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div>',
    option: ['انگور', 'ابر', 'اسب', 'اره'],
    answer: 'اسب'
  },
  {
    question: 'تصویر زیر چیست؟<br><img src="https://www.linkpicture.com/q/ara.jpg" type="image" id="img3"><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:36.819%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/alif.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:46.958%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:57.097%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(4).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:67.235%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(3).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div>',
    option: ['اسب', 'انگور', 'ابر', 'اره'],
    answer: 'اره'
  },
  {
    question: 'تصویر زیر چیست؟<br><img src="https://www.linkpicture.com/q/abr.jpg" type="image" id="img4"><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:36.819%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(3).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:46.958%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:57.097%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/alif.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:67.235%;"><audio   controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(4).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div>',
    option: ['اره', 'انگور', 'اسب', 'ابر'],
    answer: 'ابر'
  },
  {
    question: 'تصویر زیر چیست؟<br><img src="https://www.linkpicture.com/q/anar.jpg" type="image" id="img5"><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:36.819%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(3).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:46.958%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/alif.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:57.097%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com)%20(4).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div><br><div style="position:absolute; left:67.708%;top:67.235%;"><audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"><source src="https://github.com/haroon123321/audio/raw/main/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></div>',
    option: ['اره', 'انار', 'ابر', 'انگور'],
    answer: 'انار'

  }
]
var question = document.getElementById('question');
var questiona = document.getElementById('questiona');
var questionb = document.getElementById('questionb');
var questionc = document.getElementById('questionc');
var questiond = document.getElementById('questiond');
var questione = document.getElementById('questione');
var quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz-container');
var scorecard = document.getElementById('scorecard');
var option0 = document.getElementById('option0');
var option1 = document.getElementById('option1');
var option2 = document.getElementById('option2');
var option3 = document.getElementById('option3');
var next = document.querySelector('.next');
var bar = document.querySelector('.bar');
var barr = document.querySelector('.barr');
var barrr = document.querySelector('.barrr');
var barrrr = document.querySelector('.barrrr');
var barrrrr = document.querySelector('.barrrrr');
var points = document.getElementById('score');
var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');
var i = 0;
var b = 0;
var score = 0;

//function to display questions
function displayQuestion() {
  for (var a = 0; a < span.length; a++) {
    span[a].style.background = 'none';
  }
  question.innerHTML =questionBank[i].question;
  option0.innerHTML = questionBank[i].option[0];
  option1.innerHTML = questionBank[i].option[1];
  option2.innerHTML = questionBank[i].option[2];
  option3.innerHTML = questionBank[i].option[3];
}
//function to calculate scores
   var count = 0;
function calcScore(e) {
  if (e.innerHTML === questionBank[i].answer && score < questionBank.length) {
    score = score + 1; count = count + 1;}
    else {
    count = count + 1;
  }
    if (count === 0) {
            document.getElementById('butto5').style.background='#dfffff';
            document.getElementById('butto4').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto3').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto2').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto1').style.background='#cc8641';
        } else if (count === 1) {
            document.getElementById('butto5').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto4').style.background='#dfffff';
            document.getElementById('butto3').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto2').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto1').style.background='#cc8641';
        }
                else if (count === 2) {
            document.getElementById('butto5').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto4').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto3').style.background='#dfffff';
            document.getElementById('butto2').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto1').style.background='#cc8641';
        }
        else if (count === 3) {
            document.getElementById('butto5').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto4').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto3').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto2').style.background='#dfffff';
            document.getElementById('butto1').style.background='#cc8641';
        }
        else if (count === 4) {
            document.getElementById('butto5').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto4').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto3').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto2').style.background='#cc8641';
            document.getElementById('butto1').style.background='#dfffff';
        }



  setTimeout(nextQuestion, 300);
}
//function to display next question
function nextQuestion() {
  if (i < questionBank.length - 1) {
    i = i + 1;
    displayQuestion();
  } 
//SCORES
   else {
      let points;
       if (score == 5){
          points="<a href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/quiz4/quiz.html'>Good Job</a>";document.getElementById("score").onclick = function() {score00();} }
       if (score == 4){
          points="<a href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/quiz3/quiz.html'>Good Job</a>";document.getElementById("score").onclick = function() {score00();}}
       if (score == 3){
          points="<a href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/quiz1-3/quiz.html'>Good Job</a>";document.getElementById("score").onclick = function() {score00();}}
       if (score == 2){
          points="<a href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/alif/levelup.html'>Good Job</a>";document.getElementById("score").onclick = function() {score00();score2()};} 
       if (score == 1){
          points="<a href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/alif/levelup.html'>Good Job</a>";document.getElementById("score").onclick = function() {score00();score1()};} 
       if (score == 0){
           points="<a href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/alif/levelup.html'>Good Job</a>";document.getElementById("score").onclick = function() {score00();score0()};} 
           document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = points;
    quizContainer.style.display = 'none';
    scoreboard.style.display = 'block';
  }}
//bara
function nextQuestiona() {
  if (i < questionBank.length - 1) {
    i = i = 0;
    displayQuestion();
}}
//barb
function nextQuestionb() {
  if (i < questionBank.length - 1) {
    i = i = 1;
    displayQuestion();
  }
}
//barc
function nextQuestionc() {
  if (i < questionBank.length - 1) {
    i = i = 2;
    displayQuestion();
  }
}
//bard
function nextQuestiond() {
  if (i < questionBank.length - 1) {
    i = i = 3;
    displayQuestion();
  }
}
//bare
function nextQuestione() {
  if (i < questionBank.length - 1) {
    i = i = 4;
    displayQuestion();
  }
}
//click events to next button
next.addEventListener('click', nextQuestion);
bar.addEventListener('click', nextQuestiona);
barr.addEventListener('click', nextQuestionb);
barrr.addEventListener('click', nextQuestionc);
barrrr.addEventListener('click', nextQuestiond);
barrrrr.addEventListener('click', nextQuestione);
//Back to Quiz button event
function backToQuiz() {
  location.reload();
}

//function to check Answers
function checkAnswer() {
  var answerBank = document.getElementById('answerBank');
  var answers = document.getElementById('answers');
  answerBank.style.display = 'block';
  scoreboard.style.display = 'none';
  for (var a = 0; a < questionBank.length; a++) {
    var list = document.createElement('li');
    list.innerHTML = questionBank[a].answer;
    answers.appendChild(list);
  }
}
displayQuestion();




function score0() {
  localStorage.score0 ="document.getElementById('0').style.background='#49e2f8';document.getElementById('2').disabled=true;document.getElementById('3').disabled=true;document.getElementById('4').disabled=true;document.getElementById('5').disabled=true;document.getElementById('6').disabled=true;document.getElementById('7').disabled=true;document.getElementById('8').disabled=true;document.getElementById('9').disabled=true;document.getElementById('10').disabled=true;document.getElementById('11').disabled=true;document.getElementById('12').disabled=true;document.getElementById('13').disabled=true;document.getElementById('14').disabled=true;document.getElementById('15').disabled=true;document.getElementById('16').disabled=true;document.getElementById('17').disabled=true;document.getElementById('18').disabled=true;document.getElementById('19').disabled=true;document.getElementById('20').disabled=true;document.getElementById('21').disabled=true;document.getElementById('22').disabled=true;document.getElementById('23').disabled=true;document.getElementById('24').disabled=true;document.getElementById('25').disabled=true;document.getElementById('26').disabled=true;document.getElementById('27').disabled=true;document.getElementById('28').disabled=true;document.getElementById('29').disabled=true;document.getElementById('30').disabled=true;document.getElementById('30').disabled=true;document.getElementById('31').disabled=true;document.getElementById('32').disabled=true;";
}  
function score1() {
    localStorage.score1 = "document.getElementById('0').style.background='#49e2f8';document.getElementById('2').disabled=true;document.getElementById('3').disabled=true;document.getElementById('4').disabled=true;document.getElementById('5').disabled=true;document.getElementById('6').disabled=true;document.getElementById('7').disabled=true;document.getElementById('8').disabled=true;document.getElementById('9').disabled=true;document.getElementById('10').disabled=true;document.getElementById('11').disabled=true;document.getElementById('12').disabled=true;document.getElementById('13').disabled=true;document.getElementById('14').disabled=true;document.getElementById('15').disabled=true;document.getElementById('16').disabled=true;document.getElementById('17').disabled=true;document.getElementById('18').disabled=true;document.getElementById('19').disabled=true;document.getElementById('20').disabled=true;document.getElementById('21').disabled=true;document.getElementById('22').disabled=true;document.getElementById('23').disabled=true;document.getElementById('24').disabled=true;document.getElementById('25').disabled=true;document.getElementById('26').disabled=true;document.getElementById('27').disabled=true;document.getElementById('28').disabled=true;document.getElementById('29').disabled=true;document.getElementById('30').disabled=true;document.getElementById('30').disabled=true;document.getElementById('31').disabled=true;document.getElementById('32').disabled=true;";
}    
function score2() {
      localStorage.score2 = "document.getElementById('0').style.background='#49e2f8';document.getElementById('2').disabled=true;document.getElementById('3').disabled=true;document.getElementById('4').disabled=true;document.getElementById('5').disabled=true;document.getElementById('6').disabled=true;document.getElementById('7').disabled=true;document.getElementById('8').disabled=true;document.getElementById('9').disabled=true;document.getElementById('10').disabled=true;document.getElementById('11').disabled=true;document.getElementById('12').disabled=true;document.getElementById('13').disabled=true;document.getElementById('14').disabled=true;document.getElementById('15').disabled=true;document.getElementById('16').disabled=true;document.getElementById('17').disabled=true;document.getElementById('18').disabled=true;document.getElementById('19').disabled=true;document.getElementById('20').disabled=true;document.getElementById('21').disabled=true;document.getElementById('22').disabled=true;document.getElementById('23').disabled=true;document.getElementById('24').disabled=true;document.getElementById('25').disabled=true;document.getElementById('26').disabled=true;document.getElementById('27').disabled=true;document.getElementById('28').disabled=true;document.getElementById('29').disabled=true;document.getElementById('30').disabled=true;document.getElementById('30').disabled=true;document.getElementById('31').disabled=true;document.getElementById('32').disabled=true;";
}
function score00(){
    localStorage.score0001= "document.getElementById('butto1').hidden=true;document.getElementById('butto2').hidden=true;document.getElementById('butto3').hidden=true;document.getElementById('butto4').hidden=true;document.getElementById('butto5').hidden=true;document.getElementById('1').hidden=false;document.getElementById('1').disabled=false;";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family:yaqout;
  background-color: #72ccbe;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/9TVbd8G/asd.jpg');
}

img {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 45.833vw;
  margin-top:-3.4vh;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
    width:10.416vw;
    position:absolute;
}
#img1{
    margin-top:0rem;
    margin-left:-20.833vw;
}
#img2{
    margin-top:3.415vh;
    margin-left:-25.833vw;
}
#img3{
    margin-top:12.806vh;
    margin-left:-26vw;
}
#img4{
    margin-top:12.806vh;
    margin-left:-26vw;
}
#img5{
    margin-top:10.24vh;
    margin-left:-26vw;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.366vw 0;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  color: white;
  background: #00498d;
  border-radius:10px;
  font-family:yaqout;
}

.questions {
  margin: 14.941vh 25vw;
  width: 50vw;
  height:25vw;
  padding: 0.341vh;
  background: #dfffff;
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.083vw;
  color: #dfffff;
}

#question {
  margin-bottom: -33%;
  margin-left: 18.33vw;
  color: black;
  font-weight:100;
}
.option {
  margin-bottom: 2.15%;
  margin-left: 25.83vw;
  font-size: 2.33vw;
  border-bottom: wheat;
  width: 16.66vw;
  background: #dfffff;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  text-align: right;
  color: black;
}
/* CSS FOR THOSE CIRCLES */
.circle {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:2px solid #045990;
    left:68vw;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 1.5%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 1.3%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-top:20%
}
#circle0{
top:0em;
}
#circle1{
top:2.4em;
}
#circle2{
top:4.8em;
}
#circle3{
top:7.2em;
}
.option:hover {
  color: wheat;
}
/* END OF CSS FOR THOSE CIRCLES */
ol {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1.25vw;
  color: black;
}

span {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.017vh 0.75vw;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

#answer {
  margin-top: 0rem;
}

#stat {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  color: white;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 3.415vh 1.66vw;
  width:8.335vw;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.66vw;
  background: #cc8641;
  border-top-right-radius: 26vw;
  border-top-left-radius: 26vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:traffic;
  margin-right:1.96vw;
}


.progressbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25vw;
  bottom: 71vh;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#butto5{
    background:#dfffff;
}
#home {
position:relative;
bottom:14.94vh;
right:-1.458vw;
width:50.5vw;
height:10.672vh;
border-top-left-radius:0;
border-top-right-radius:0;
border-bottom-left-radius:2rem;
border-bottom-right-radius:2rem;
background: #00498d;
cursor:pointer;
font-family:yaqout;
color:white;
font-size: 2.5vw;
}
#home1 {
position:relative;
bottom:24.54vh;
right:26.04vw;
width:50.5vw;
height:10.672vh;
cursor:pointer;
font-family:yaqout;
color:white;
font-size: 2.5vw;
}

#scoreboard,
#answerBank {
  width: 20rem;
  background: #ee6c4d;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 5rem;
  display: none;
}

#score-title {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
#check-answer {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

#score {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

#answerBank li {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  font-size: larger;
}

#answers {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

audio {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
     audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
     background-color: #dfffff;
     color: #dfffff;
     }
/* Removes the timeline */
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  display: none;
}

/* Removes the time stamp */
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {
  display: none;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {
  display: none;
}

/* Removes mute-button */
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
  display: none;
}

/* Removes mute-button */
audio::-webkit-media-controls-playbackrate {
  display: none;
}

/* Removes mute-button */
audio::-webkit-media-controls-download {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="quiz.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Quiz</title>

        <!-- css file link -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="quiz.css">
      </head>

      <body>
        <h1 id="title">پیش آزمون</h1>
        <!-- quiz-container -->
        <div id="quiz-container">
          <!-- question container -->
          <div class="questions">
            <h2 id="question"></h2>
            <ul type="none">
              <li class="option"><span id="option0" onclick="calcScore(this)"></span></li>
              <li class="option"><span id="option1" onclick="calcScore(this)"></span></li>
              <li class="option"><span id="option2" onclick="calcScore(this)"></span></li>
              <li class="option"><span id="option3" onclick="calcScore(this)"></span></li>
            <!--  HTML FOR THOSE CIRCLES -->
              <div class="circle" id="circle0"></div>
              <div class="circle" id="circle1"></div>
              <div class="circle" id="circle2"></div>
              <div class="circle" id="circle3"></div>
            <!--  END OF THE HTML FOR THOSE CIRCLES -->
            </ul>
            <h4 id="stat"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <a href="https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/alif%20ta%20ya/alif-ya.html"><button type="button" class="btn succes" id="home"></button></a>
            <p id="home1">خانه</p>
            <p class="next"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
      <!-- progressbar -->
      <div class=progressbar>
        <button id="butto1" class="bar" onclick="function1(); eval(localStorage.getItem('a001'));">۵</button>
        <button id="butto2" class="barr" onclick="function2(); eval(localStorage.getItem('a002'));">۴</button>
        <button id="butto3" class="barrr" onclick="function3(); eval(localStorage.getItem('a003'));">۳</button>
        <button id="butto4" class="barrrr" onclick="function4(); eval(localStorage.getItem('a004'));">۲</button>
        <button id="butto5" class="barrrrr" onclick="function5(); eval(localStorage.getItem('a005'));">۱</button>
        <script src="quiz.js"></script>
        <script>
                    function function5(){
                localStorage.a005="document.getElementById('butto1').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto2').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto3').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto4').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto5').style.background='#dfffff';";
            }
            function function4(){
                localStorage.a004="document.getElementById('butto1').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto2').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto3').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto4').style.background='#dfffff';document.getElementById('butto5').style.background='#cc8641';";
            }
            function function3(){
                localStorage.a003="document.getElementById('butto1').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto2').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto3').style.background='#dfffff';document.getElementById('butto4').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto5').style.background='#cc8641';";
            }
            function function2(){
                localStorage.a002="document.getElementById('butto1').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto2').style.background='#dfffff';document.getElementById('butto3').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto4').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto5').style.background='#cc8641';";
            }
            function function1(){
                localStorage.a001="document.getElementById('butto1').style.background='#dfffff';document.getElementById('butto2').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto3').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto4').style.background='#cc8641';document.getElementById('butto5').style.background='#cc8641';";
            }
        </script>
      </div>
      <!-- scoreboard section -->
      <div id="scoreboard">
        <button id="score" ></button>
        <button id="btndelete" onclick="btndelete()" style="display:none"></button>
        <script>
            function btndelete(){
                 eval(localStorage.getItem("score0001"));
            }
setInterval(function () {document.getElementById("btndelete").click();}, 10);
setInterval(function () {document.getElementById("score").click();}, 10);
        </script>
      <script src="quiz.js"></script>
      </div>

      <!-- answers section -->
      <div id="answerBank">
        <h2>Answers :</h2>
        <ol type="1" id="answers">

      <!-- javascript file source -->
      <script src="quiz.js"></script>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Also the code the specific html and css code for the circles is labeled. The css for it line 86 and is labeled. The html for the code starts at line 26 and is labeled. You dont need any Js and if you have a question about the code ill be happy to answer. Also i have a jsfiddle if this isnt that good https://jsfiddle.net/zp2ha3oe/

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem, I think you should to use a **media query** for responsive all devices. Check it here my media query... it as simple just put your CSS here, which devices you want to change something.

```
/* Normal desktop :1200px. */
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1500px) {

/*     put your css */
}


/* Normal desktop :992px. */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {

  /*     put your css */
}

 
/* Tablet desktop :768px. */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

  /*     put your css */
}

 
/* small mobile :320px. */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

 /*     put your css */
  
}
```